# Matlab SVM for Image Classification

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, classification, svm

I am using SVM function of Matlab to classify images that are read from a folder. What I want to do is first read 20 images from the folder, then use these to train the SVM, and then give a new image as input to decide whether this input image falls into the same category of these 20 training images or not. If it is, then the classification result should give me `1`, if not, then I expect to receive `-1`.

Up to now, my written code is as follows:

```
imagefiles = dir('*.jpg');
nfiles = 20; 

for i = 1:nfiles
    currentfilename = imagefiles(i).name;
    currentimage = imread(currentfilename);
    images{i} = currentimage;
    images{i} = im2double(images{i});
    images{i} = rgb2gray(images{i});
    images{i} = imresize(images{i},[200 200]);
    images{i} = reshape(images{i}', 1, size(images{i},1)*size(images{i},2));
end

trainData = zeros(nfiles, 40000);

for ii=1:nfiles
    trainData(ii,:) = images{ii};
end

class = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
SVMStruct = svmtrain (trainData, class);

inputImg = imread('testImg.jpg');
inputImg = im2double(inputImg);
inputImg = rgb2gray(inputImg);
inputImg = imresize(inputImg, [200 200]);
inputImg = reshape (inputImg', 1, size(inputImg,1)*size(inputImg,2));
result = svmclassify(SVMStruct, inputImg);
```

Since the images are read by series from the folder, so camethe cell `images`. Then I converted them to grayscale as shown in the code, and resized them, since those images were NOT of same size. Thus after this step, I had 20 images, all of each with size `200x200`. And at last, I gave these to serve as my training dataset, with `20` rows, and `200x200` columns. I checked all of these size results, and they seemed to work fine. But right now the only problem is, no matter what kind of input image I give it to predict, it always gives me a result as `1`, even for those very different images. Seems like it is not working correctly. Could someone help me check out where should be the problem here? I couldn't find any explanation from the existing sources on the internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `images{i} = im2double(images{ii});` Why `ii`?

Comment: Does it return 1 on images from the training set which have a class of -1 ?

Comment: sorry, for the {ii}, I typed it incorrectly in my question here. I edited it.

Comment: @Photon: I can try it on the training set then will give you more information. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I solved this by myself. Thank you all for your interest.

Comment: @E_learner: can you give me the complete source that workable (you say that you can solve it by yourself). Because in your question the training data for each image is an array of 1 dimension (you convert RGB image to grayscale and then reshape it to 1 dimension),  whereas in accepted question in this thread the image still in RGB format. 
I dont understand how that answer solve your problem. Can I passing RGB image for training data in MATLAB 'svmtrain' function

Comment: @E_learner: i need to implementing SVM for my current task, and I think your question makes my task easier. Sorry I have no background in image processing

Comment: @fajar66: the accepted answer is for reading image series in a correct way, since that is the problem in my original question. You then can take reference to the rest part of my code for SVM classification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function to read all images that may help you

```
function X = ReadImgs(Folder,ImgType)
Imgs = dir(fullfile(Folder, ImgType));
NumImgs = size(Imgs,1);
image = double(imread(fullfile(Folder, Imgs(1).name)));
X = zeros([NumImgs size(image)]);
for i=1:NumImgs,
  img = double(imread(fullfile(Folder, Imgs(i).name)));
  if (size(image,3) == 1)
    X(i,:,:) = img;
  else
    X(i,:,:,:) = img;
end
end
```

Source: http://computervisionblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/matlab-read-all-images-from-a-folder-everything-starts-here/

Answer (score 0):

this is should be works in MATLAB

```
clear all; 
clc; 

folder = 'gambar 1'; 
dirImage = dir( folder ); 

numData = size(dirImage,1); 

M ={} ; 

% read image 
for i=1:numData
    nama = dirImage(i).name;  
    if regexp(nama, '(lion|tiger)-[0-9]{1,2}.jpg')
        B = cell(1,2); 
        if regexp(nama, 'lion-[0-9]{1,2}.jpg')
            B{1,1} = double(imread([folder, '/', nama]));
            B{1,2} = 1; 
        elseif regexp(nama, 'tiger-[0-9]{1,2}.jpg')
            B{1,1} = double(imread([folder, '/', nama]));
            B{1,2} = -1; 
        end
        M = cat(1,M,B); 
    end 
end

% convert image holder from cell to array
numDataTrain = size(M,1); 
class = zeros(numDataTrain,1);
arrayImage = zeros(numDataTrain, 300 * 300);

for i=1:numDataTrain
    im = M{i,1} ;
    im = rgb2gray(im); 
    im = imresize(im, [300 300]); 
    im = reshape(im', 1, 300*300); 
    arrayImage(i,:) = im; 
    class(i) = M{i,2}; 
end

SVMStruct = svmtrain(arrayImage, class);

% test for lion
lionTest = double(imread('gambar 1/lion-test.jpg' )); 
lionTest = rgb2gray(lionTest); 
lionTest = imresize(lionTest, [300 300]); 
lionTest = reshape(lionTest',1, 300*300); 
result = svmclassify(SVMStruct, lionTest);  

result
```

https://github.com/gunungloli666/svm-test